# Find $\mathbb E((N(1,4]|N(3,10]=7))$ where $(N_t, t\geq 0)$ is a Poisson counting process with $\lambda=1$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, conditional-probability

Find $\mathbb E((N(1,4]|N(3,10]=7))$ where $(N_t, t\geq 0)$ is a poisson counting process with rate $\lambda=1$

**Attempt:**

First determine conditional pmf:
\begin{align}
f_{N(1,4]|N(3,10]}(x|y) &= \frac{f_{N(1,4],N(3,10]}(x,y)}{f_{N(3,10]}(y)}
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
\mathbb E((N(1,4]|N(3,10]=7)) &= \sum_x xf_{N(1,4]|N(3,10]}(x|y)
\end{align}
I'm having trouble determining the joint pmf since the intervals overlap, and does $x$ range from 0 to $\infty$ in the summation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} (N(1,4]|N(3,10]=7)&=\mathbb{E} (N(1,3)|N(3,10]=7) + \mathbb{E} (N[3,4]|N(3,10]=7)\\
&=\mathbb{E} (N(1,3)) + \mathbb{E} (N[3,4]|N(3,10]=7)\\
&= 2 + \frac{4-3}{10-3}\cdot 7
\end{align}

As for your question should $x$ range from $0$ to $\infty$, yes.

Comment: thanks, how did you evaluate $\mathbb E(N[3,4]|N(3,10]=7)$?

Comment: Given the total arrivals, it can be proved that the the arrivals time are uniformly distributed.

Comment: [Section 2.5](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-262-discrete-stochastic-processes-spring-2011/course-notes/MIT6_262S11_chap02.pdf) might be of interest to you.

Comment: ok thanks that makes sense now. The last bit I don't get was how you were able to split $N(1,4]$ to $N(1,3]$ and $N(3,4]$. I get that they don't overlap but what's the intermediate step between the first equality

Comment: We have $N(1,4]=N(1,3]+N(3,4]$ right? total number of arrivals in $(1,4]$ is equal to the sum of number of arrivals in $(1,3]$ and the number of arrivals in $(3,4]$.